# How to send request post with file and json?

Tags: javascript, file, asp.net-core

I have a form to send to back-end. This form has entry fields and a file upload.

This is the send of my form.

```
submit () {
      console.log(this.banners)
      const banners = new FormData()
      banners.append('banners', this.banners)
      this.$axios.post(api.insertBanner, banners).then(response => response.data)
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    },
```

[console.log results in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNVS9.png)

My method POST:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Post(BannersDTO banners)
```

BannersDTO.cs

```
public class BannersDTO
{
    public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile Files { get; set; }
    public string TermoOrSku { get; set; }
    public bool InserirImediato { get; set; }
    public string DataAtivacao { get; set; }
    public string DataVigencia { get; set; }
}
```

Problem: I have received `status code 400(badRequest)`, that is, i need to modify the input because it is not correct. What is wrong?

If I modify the parts of code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Post(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile Files)

banners.append('files', this.banners.files)
```

My code works fine, but in the case I only get the file, and I also need the data.

Comment: All I see is code with no question. What is your issue and what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting with form data . Code below is for your reference :

HTML :

```
<form >
    Email:  <input asp-for="TermoOrSku" /> <br />
    files:  <input type="file" name="Files">
</form>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="Upload()" />
```

JS:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        function Upload() {
            var data = new FormData($('form').get(0));

            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: '/home/UploadFiles',
                data: data,
                config: { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    //handle success
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(function (response) {
                    //handle error
                    console.log(response);
                });

        }
    </script>

}
```

On controller side , you can get the data including the file and other input values :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFiles(BannersDTO model)
{
    // to do : read values of model and use it
    // to do : return something
    return View();
}
```